# How to convert a JSON array which is not having JSON object in Java using List or Hashmap

Tags: java, android, json

How to convert this in Java using `List` or `Hashmap`?

```java
{"mappingSet": ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]}
```

Comment: Is the question here how to parse json into list or hashmap without any dependencies?

Comment: That isn't legal JSON, so I think you're going to have difficulties finding anything that would work.  That array needs to be an object.  If you really need to parse malformed JSON, you're going to have to do it by hand.

Comment: @Rohini The JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

you could use some third party lib
like

1. gson
2. jackson

then you can covert json string to

- pre-defined objects
- lib built in objects
  like JsonObject(JsonArray, JsonElement) in 1.gson
  and JsonNode in 2.jackson

example here

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonArray = "[{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"FIAT\" }, { \"color\" : \"Green\", \"type\" : \"NIKE\" }]";
    JsonNode jsonNodeArray = objectMapper.readTree(jsonArray);
    System.out.println(jsonNodeArray);
    System.out.println(jsonNodeArray.get(0));
```

Comment: inside the json array there is no json object.

Comment: by the way, I don't think your json string above is valid in format.
json array could not contain key value pair

Comment: its a valid json.

Comment: @Rohini No, it isn't.  You can't have key:value fields in an array.  Run it past a JSON validator like JSONlint-  it fails.

Comment: you can copy paste to any online json parser

Comment: I have verified it using JSON validator. it's showing as valid json